# How do you change the CircularPercentIndicator's circle area color?

Tags: flutter, dart

I know that `backgroundColor` changes the line color, and that `progressColor` also changes part of the line color. What changes the area color?

Here's what I have

[image]

Here's my goal

[image]

```
Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    Obx(
      () {
        if (settingsController
            .user.value.kicks.isNotEmpty) {
          var totalKicks = settingsController
              .user.value.kicks.length;
          var goalsArea = settingsController
              .user.value.kicks[2].kickArea;
          return CircularPercentIndicator(
            radius: 20.0,
            lineWidth: 2.0,
            percent: goalsArea / totalKicks,
            backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(
                255, 255, 150, 23),
            progressColor: Color.fromARGB(
                255, 255, 150, 23),
            center: Text(
              ((goalsArea / totalKicks) * 100)
                      .toInt()
                      .toString() +
                  "%",
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Color.fromARGB(
                    255, 255, 150, 23),
              ),
            ),
          );
        } else {
          return Text(
            "0",
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 20,
              color: Color.fromARGB(
                  255, 255, 150, 23),
            ),
          );
        }
      },
    ),
    Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 33),
      child: Text(
        "Area 2",
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        style: TextStyle(
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          color: Colors.white,
          backgroundColor:
              Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 150, 23),
        ),
      ),
    )
  ],
),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no predefined property to do that, but you can do some workaround like this:

```
ClipRRect(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
      child:
        Container(
          child:
            CircularPercentIndicator(
              fillColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 206, 175, 138),
              backgroundWidth: 0,
              radius: 20.0,
              lineWidth: 1.0,
              backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(
                  255, 255, 150, 23),
        )
    )
```

Comment: This is very close, but it fills the entire square that the circle is in, so part of the color bleeds outside of the circle.